# React no renderiza imagenes y tampoco toma classes

Tags: css, reactjs, sass

tengo un problema con react el cual no renderiza las imagenes que cargo localmente, tampoco toma las propiedades css que le estoy dando, las imagenes están correctamente añadidas ya que puedo abrirlas en una segunda pesta no se si es un error de react o de css, estoy usando el sass.

Componente:

```
import { Link, NavLink } from 'react-router-dom'
import './index.scss'
import LogoS from '../../assets/images/logo-s.png'
import LogoSubtitle from '../../assets/images/logo_sub.png'
import { FontAwesomeIcon } from '@fortawesome/react-fontawesome'
import { faEnvelope, faHome, faUser } from '@fortawesome/free-solid-svg-icons'

const Sidebar = () => (
  <div className="nav-bar">
    <Link className="logo" to="/">
      <image src={LogoS} alt="logo"/>
      <image src={LogoSubtitle} alt="robert" className="sub-logo" />
    </Link>
    <nav>
      <NavLink exact="true" activeclassname="active" to="/">
        <FontAwesomeIcon icon={faHome} color="#4d4d4e" />
      </NavLink>

      <NavLink
        exact="true"
        className="about-link"
        activeclassname="active"
        to="/about"
      >
        <FontAwesomeIcon icon={faUser} color="#4d4d4e" />
      </NavLink>

      <NavLink
        exact="true"
        className="contact-link"
        activeclassname="active"
        to="/"
      >
        <FontAwesomeIcon icon={faEnvelope} color="#4d4d4e" />
      </NavLink>
    </nav>
  </div>
)

export default Sidebar
```

Archivo scss:

```
.nav-bar{
    background-color: #181818;
    width: 60px;
    height: 100%;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    z-index: 3;
    min-height: 500px;

    .logo {
        display: block;
        padding: 8px 0;
        img {
            display: block;
            margin: 8px auto;
            width: 24px;
            height: auto;
    
            &.sub-logo{
                width: 50px;
            }
        }
    }

    nav{
        display: block;
        text-align: center;
        position: absolute;
        height: 210px;
        top: 50%;
        margin-top: -120px;
        width: 100%;

        a{
            font-size: 22px;
            color: #4d4d4e;
            display: block;
            line-height: 51px;
            height: 51px;
            position: relative;
            text-decoration: none;

            i {
                transition: all 0.3 ease-out;
            }

            &:hover {
                color: #ffd700;

                svg {
                    opacity: 0;
                }

                &::after{
                    opacity: 1;
                }
            }

            &::after{
                content: "";
                font-size: 9px;
                letter-spacing: 2px;
                position: absolute;
                bottom: 0;
                display: block;
                width: 100%;
                text-align: center;
                opacity: 0;
                transition: all ;
            }

            &:first-child {
                &::after{
                    content: 'HOME';
                }
            }

            a.about-link{
                &::after{
                    content: 'ABOUT';
                }
            }

            a.contact-link{
                &::after{
                    content: 'ABOUT';
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Pd: los elementos con la clase .contact-link y .about-link tampoco toman las propiedades css, el elemento al que selecciono con :first-child si toma el ::after para hacer una pequeña animación.

Comment: ¿Tus estilos e imágenes están fuera de la carpeta `src`?  Nota que, si creaste tu applicación con `create-react-app` todos tus los `assets` que importes en tus componentes deben estar dentro de la carpeta `src`, si no no va a funcionar. Checa para más detalles [esta respuesta](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44115058/8838721).

Comment: Si, la cree con create-react-app, y la carpeta assets están en la carpeta src, la imagen si la detecta por que puedo inspeccionarla y abrirla en una segunda pestaña, el problema es que no la renderiza, tiene un tamaño de 0x0, y no toma las propiedades que le doy con img{}

Comment: Logre solucionarlo y es un error tonto, el tag correcto es <img> y no <image>, si no react piensa que es un componente. Pero aún tengo el problema que el elemento con la clase .about-link y .contact-link no toman las propiedades pero el que selecciono con :first-child si.

Answer (score -1):

El error es simple, el verdadero tag html es `<img>`, si se escribe `<image>` react piensa que es un componente que no existe, además la razón por el cual no tomaba las propiedades css es por error con las llaves.